# How to change content on a bare-bone single page web-app in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to write a singer page, client-side web app in dart. 
I want to change dinamicly the content of my single html content.
I haven't found what's best practice to change the entire content in a fast and easy way, without loading a hole new html-file.

My idea was dealing all children of the body tag, and replace it with a body tag html snippet from an other html-file.
Problem: I don't know if it's best practice, and how to achieve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was what I'm searched for! 
I didn't noticed that it is that easy to read content from a file.
The code below shows the solution of my problem.

```
var gameHtml = 'game.html';

HttpRequest.getString(gameHtml)
    .then((String fileContent) {
      body.innerHtml = fileContent;
    });
```

So after reading the content of 'game.html' i placed the String in my 'index.html' body-tag.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-html/HttpRequest-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use the browser API to remove and add content.

```
document.body.innerHtml = `<body><div>Hello, World!</div></body>`;
```

or

```
document.body.children.clear();
document.body.children.add(DivElement()..text = 'Hello, World!');
```

See also https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-html/Element-class.html

You can do everything the browser can do. For example what's explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API